# Python syntax issue in print statment

Tags: python

I started learning python and stuck at very basic question. Not able to resolve this on my own or from google and need your help.

When I run this code. This is what I expect in output.

---

```
pizzas = ['Cheese Pizza', 'Veggie Pizza', 'Spicy Pizza']
for i in pizzas:
    print ("I love " + i)
print ("Actually I donot like pizza that much. Its unhealthy")
```

---

**Expected Output**

```
I love Cheese Pizza
I love Veggie Pizza
I love Spicy Pizza
Actually I donot like pizza that much. Its unhealthy
```

---

**Error**

```
File "<stdin>", line 3
print ("Actually I donot like pizza that much. Its unhealthy")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

I am using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: First: 2.6.6? That's pretty severely out of date. Second: interactive mode or script? It sounds like you typed this in in interactive mode, in which case compound statements like `for` loops have to end in a blank line

Comment: @user2357112 it's definitely the interactive mode thing.. exact same error even in 3.6 with no other typos.

Comment: *Hint:*  File "<stdin>", line 3

Comment: worked fine in python 3.5

Comment: hey, thanks for quick reply. I was using interactive mode. It ran fine in script mode. As suggested it worked fine in interactive mode once I kept blank line in first and 2nd print in above code. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes..using 2.6.6 and its old. I was using my secondary laptop..which have this by default.

Comment: Now as I understood what causing this..posting URL for others reference. 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Interactive_mode

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the () after the print function in python 2.x

so: 
print ("I love " + i) should be print "I love " + i
print ("Actually I donot like pizza that much. Its unhealthy") should be print "Actually I donot like pizza that much. Its unhealthy"

iDonut shouldn't be one to talk...